# Mots Loucherbem passés dans la langue courante

Tags: argot, loucherbem

Je viens de découvrir que *loufoque* est la version loucherbem de *fou*.

Y a-t-il d'autres mots de louchébem qui sont passés dans la langue courante?

---

I've just found out that *loufoque* is the "loucherbem" (French slang akin to Pig Latin) version of *fou*.

Are there other "louchébem" words which have passed into common French?

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Louchébem#Le_louch.C3.A9bem_pass.C3.A9_dans_le_fran.C3.A7ais_courant

Comment: Heu... lardonpem ?

Answer (score 7):

Sur la page [louchébem](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louch%C3%A9bem) de Wikipédia, il y a une section sur [le louchébem passé dans le français courant](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louch%C3%A9bem#Le_louch.C3.A9bem_pass.C3.A9_dans_le_fran.C3.A7ais_courant).

Pour ma part, je connaissais les mots *en loucedé* et *larfeuille*.